# VBA Issue with Selenium Library for Dynamic Website, Unable to close pop up window

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

[image]

I'm trying to do the web scraping for a website which is dynamically loaded, I tried everything today to close the popup icon or clicking "No thanks", but it is not working and I am getting error showing in screenshot.

I need to fetch the product name, new and old price and their href image URL in excel.

```
Option Explicit
Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Findingelement()


Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

cd.Start
cd.Get "https://www.westelm.com/shop/furniture/all-living-room/?cm_type=gnav&originsc=furniture"

Dim dismiss As Selenium.WebElement
Dim findby As New Selenium.By
Dim closepopup As Selenium.WebElement

Set dismiss = cd.FindElement(findby.Class("dismiss-overlay-text"))
dismiss.Click

Set closepopup = cd.FindElement(findby.XPath("//div[@class='no-thanks']/a[@class='overlayCloseButton stickyHeaderCloseButton not-into-savings']"))
closepopup.Click


End Sub
```

Comment: Elements with those class names do not appear to exist on that page? (loading the given url redirects to the home page)

Comment: @NickSlash i have started learning coding recently, and i got this project. I have seen many videos and try to get the solution both in Python and VBA. Yes, though i have mentioned a different address it behaves like a home page, but if u manually closing the popup, it is taking me to the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you are trying to scrape seems to serve different popups depending on where you are located.

The following code dismisses a "view your local site" popup, and a "join our mailing list" popup if viewed from UAE.

You need to give the WebDriver time to render the document before you try to interact with it. The `timeout` parameter on the `FindElement*` functions helps with this, allowing time for them to become available.

This is still not a guarantee that the elements were found, so testing to see if the result is `Nothing` before attempting to click is a good idea.

I don't think you need the `Selenium.By` as you can use `WebDriver.FindElementByXPath`

```
Public Driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Main()
Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim Element As Selenium.WebElement

Driver.Get "https://www.westelm.com/shop/furniture/all-living-room/?cm_type=gnav&originsc=furniture"

Set Element = Driver.FindElementByClass("dismiss-overlay-text", 5000) ' wait max of 5000ms (5s) for element to be available

If Element Is Nothing Then
   Debug.Print "failed: dismiss overlay"
Else
    Debug.Print "success: dismissed overlay"
    Element.Click
End If
    
Set Element = Driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='join-email']/div/div[3]/div/a", 5000)

If Element Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "failed: dismiss promotion"
Else
    Debug.Print "success: dismissed promotion"
    Element.Click
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly this time script took me to products pages. Now I will try to get the detials of product using the similar method, thank you so much.